# Exporting RSpec tests from Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rspec

I am testing using Docker to run my ruby on rails Rspec tests.  This will allow me greater flexibility to test against different databases etc.

In our Bamboo pipeline, its all working - except I assume the rspec.xml file is being placed inside the docker container, and not into the Bamboo working directory.  If any tests fail - the bamboo job fails and number of tests is now **not** reported in bamboo and I assume its because of the 'missing' rspec.xml file.

We have a JUnit XML parser task which now also fails since it cannot find the XML output, and since the docker container is deleted at the end of the tests I assume the file will be deleted also.

Is there anyway to output this file to the Bamboo working directory?

Running the specs like this:

```
 docker run --volume /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DIR-ABS2711-UTJGB:/usr/src/app --rm --env RAILS_ENV=test bond:latest bundle exec rake db:migrate rspec_tests:model_tests:run
```

Note that I am using a `rake` task to run the specs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in order to have rspec output results in xml you need something like this:

```
rspec -r rspec_junit_formatter --format RspecJunitFormatter -o rspec.xml
```

But since I am using a rake task I cannot use that, I instead need to modify my rake task to out to xml:

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
  t.fail_on_error = false
  t.rspec_opts = "--no-drb -r rspec_junit_formatter --format RspecJunitFormatter -o rspec.xml"
end
```